# Sending SMS from Java Application using communications API

Tags: java, sms

I am using `Java Communications API`. Want to know that is it compulsory to set CSCA (Service Center Address) using the AT command: `AT+CSCA=` for sending sms through java application? Or we can just skip that part and send the AT Command `AT+CMGS=` to send the message? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your sending via a hardware device with a SIM card; that card will most likely come configured with a profile that specifies the home networks service centre number - after all you don't have to enter one yourself when you acquire a SIM for your own phone.

You can test for one with `+CSCA?`.

Comment: Yes. I have tested it. When i execute this command `+CSCA?`, response received is `OK`. So it means that i could skip the part where CSCA is set using `+CSCA=`?

Comment: It should response with +CSCA:xxxxx\r\nOK (you may need to activate verbose responses with ATV1)

Comment: Yes response is the same as you have mentioned. Is there any possibility that there is no CSCA number configured inside the SIM?

Comment: Most sims come pre-configured with the carriers details but I suppose its possible that some do not ... if you want to be defensive add detection code that checks +CSCA? and inform the user, or wait for the 1st send to fail.

Comment: And if it fails then i should get the CSCA from my DB and set it using `+CSCA=`. Well i was hoping to get rid of fetching CSCA from DB. But to be on the safe side i should always set it. What do you suggest?

Comment: It will most likely be there for you to use as carriers ship sims configured for use, I would say not finding one would be an edge case

Comment: Well, that's your call, I've shipped GSM software in the UK to a couple of hundred users all of whom provided their own sims and never had an issue with missing csca config (there is a test for it, if one were to be missing it informs the user to ask their carrier for one)

Comment: So i also need to handle the edge case. No?

Comment: Oh ok its good to go then! So i should also implement this that if csca is missing it should inform the user! :)

Answer (score 0):

It’s been a while since I messed around with GSM but I think you only need to configure the service center if you intend to send messages in text format. When using binary PDUs the SMSC number needs to be specified for each SMS you send.

Comment: Well i'm sending SMS in PDU format and have tried to send it without setting the CSCA. And it was successful. So i think there is no explicit need to set it because it is already configured inside the SIM.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an example for sending sms with AT commands some time ago on my blog. It's in C# but the AT commands should stay the same, have a look at http://www.softwarepassion.com/your-personal-sms-gateway-with-c/